1930s house ceiling sagging with a rectangular pattern. What should be done about this?
Just moved into a house built in the 1930s and the ceiling in the dining room has sagging ceiling in a rectangular pattern and some cracking as well. I’m not sure if the previous owner did anything with this ceiling so I can’t say for certain if it’s plaster and lath, but that’s what the rest of the house is so I assume this ceiling is as well. Above this ceiling is a second floor bedroom.
Two questions:

How urgent is this to fix?
How should it be fixed?



At first glance, looks to me like badly taped and possibly badly anchored plasterboard. But I can't see how much it's "sagging".

1930s also means the possibility of lead paint(with a touch of asbestos), so in worst case of replacement needed, be careful.  Might be easier to just fur across the joists and add new drywall.  Lead paint and/or asbestos are only dangerous(minor) if removed/chewed on.  Why lead paint and young children do not mix well.

@keshlam Ah so that rectangular pattern where it's badly taped likely points to the ceiling NOT being lathe and plaster right?

@BryanCoxwell: Not sure from the photo but that would be my guess.

You need to find out what it is. Take the light fixture down and examine the opening, or drill a hole.

You can't rule out drywall/sheetrock attached to lathe and plaster. Sheet goods attached to sagging plaster and lathe results in wavy sagging ceiling. As@ isherwood has  suggested check around the light fixture or if available a visual from the attic.

I second removing the fixture to see what layers of ceiling exist.  Plus, look in the wall outlets in the room above this one and adjacent rooms to determine the age of the upstairs wiring.  If this is an original ceiling there's some chance your upstairs wiring is original or very old.  If you aren't sure whether to repair or replace, the opportunity to upgrade the wiring for two or three upstairs rooms is a factor.  With the ceiling down you can do it.

In a 1930's house with plaster, you appear to have "rock lath", which means that a thin lath similar to modern drywall is nailed to the joists, and then plaster is applied over that.  Each of the rectangles you see are one sheet of rock lath.
I've seen this sort of effect happen a lot.  In my experience, the problem is only cosmetic, it's not about to fall on your head or anything.
If you don't like the look of it, fixing it is not easy though.  You can certainly tear it all down and replace with drywall.  If the amount of sag is not too great, you could skimcoat it with more plaster or joint compound, although there is a risk it will sag more and still end up with the sagging effect.  You will also need to tape the joints to prevent cracks from coming back.
I have some places like this in my house, we've taken down the ceiling in one room that looked pretty bad.  Other rooms aren't so bad and I've gotten away with taping and mudding the cracks that developed at the seams.  Other rooms are decent enough that I've elected to ignore the problem.

skim coating sagging rock lath is utterly a waste of time and sounds like a disaster.

Sometimes the "sag" is really quite minor, and more importantly is stable.  With the light coming at a glancing angle, it can really emphasize tiny amounts of unevenness that is not noticeable with direct light, and otherwise might only be detected by running your hand over it.  I can't see the OP's situation in person to make a judgment, maybe it really is bad enough that it ought to come down.  I just wanted to note that sometimes you can get away with filing in the low spots between the bulges and it can work.
